# Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider Alternative

Tags: forms-authentication

I have a SP 2010 set up using claims based authentication and the Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider provider.  Everything for user authentication works perfectly but when I try to change a user's password in code it fails with **"Method Not Implemented"**.

After searching around the internet it has become apparent that the LdapMembershipProvider is extremely limited and allows for almost no interaction and modification of user accounts beyond basic authentication; so my question is this: **is there an alternative to the LdapMembershipProvider class?**  Or, is there a way in code to change a user's password with the LdapMembershipProvider?  The LDAP store is Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint uses ASP.NET 2.0 provider model, at is extendable. You can create your own membership and role provider if you have special functionality you need implemented.

If you do a google search ou will find lots of guides on how to create custom providers that auenticate with AD or custom databases.

Further references:

[ADSI forum on MS forum](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.adsi.general/topics)

MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx) on provider model

[directoryprogramming.net](http://directoryprogramming.net/)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to not have to go down that road but it looks like I'm not going to have any choice.